# peewee multiprocess from separate db connection 'peewee.OperationalError: disk I/O error'

Tags: python, peewee

I am trying to use multiprocessing in order to run a CPU-intensive job in the background. I'd like this process to be able to use peewee ORM to write its results to the SQLite database.

In order to do so, I am trying to override the Meta.database of my model class after thread creation so that I can have a separate db connection for my new process.

```
def get_db():
    db = SqliteExtDatabase(path)
    return db

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = get_db()

# Many other models

class Batch(BaseModel):
    
    def multi():
        def background_proc():
            # trying to override Meta's db connection.
            BaseModel._meta.database = get_db()
            job = Job.get_by_id(1)
            print("working in the background")
        
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=background_proc)
        process.start()
```

Error when executing `my_batch.multi()`

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/layne/Desktop/pydatasci/pydatasci/aidb/__init__.py", line 1249, in background_proc
    job = Job.get_by_id(1)
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 6395, in get_by_id
    return cls.get(cls._meta.primary_key == pk)
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 6384, in get
    return sq.get()
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 6807, in get
    return clone.execute(database)[0]
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1886, in inner
    return method(self, database, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1957, in execute
    return self._execute(database)
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2129, in _execute
    cursor = database.execute(self)
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3112, in execute
    return self.execute_sql(sql, params, commit=commit)
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3106, in execute_sql
    self.commit()
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2873, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(exc_value, *exc_args), traceback)
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 183, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
peewee.OperationalError: disk I/O error
```

I got this working using threads instead, but it's hard to actually terminate a thread (not just break from a loop) and CPU-intensive (not io  delayed) jobs should be multiprocessed.

UPDATE: looking into peewee proxy http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#dynamically-defining-a-database

Comment: You cannot have more than one process connect and update to SQLite concurrently. You cannot even more than one thread concurrently updating SQLite. Unless you compile SQLite with multi-threading support. A possible solution is to have each process acquire a lock on the entire file prior to opening it and writing to it.

Comment: @Tarik, that is incorrect, SQLite does support multiple connections. You just need to be careful since writes lock the entire DB. Charles (author of peewee) even has a [blog post](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/sqlite-small-fast-reliable-choose-any-three-/) about this

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax, as an alternative, what about having the child threads/processes just write the results to separate files/buffers and then the main process can combine them all and write to the DB?

Comment: @booshong thank you. yes, that would work with some pickle files. i've figured out the connection though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem was that:

Within the separate process, I was not closing the existing connection before attempting to replace it with a new connection.

```py
def background_proc():
    db = BaseModel._meta.database
    db.close() #<----- this
    BaseModel._meta.database = get_db()
```

This works and I can continue to use the original connection on my main process (or whatever the non-multiprocess called).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe init DB Object in each process will help you.

```
def get_db():
    db = SqliteExtDatabase(path)
    return db

class BaseModel(Model):

    def __init__(self, database, **kwargs):
        self.database = database

# Many other models

class Batch(BaseModel):
    
    def multi():
        def background_proc():
            # trying to override Meta's db connection.
            db = get_db()
            basemodel = BaseModel(db)
            # do something like "basemodel.insert(name="Alex")"
            job = Job(db)
            result = job.get_by_id(1)
            print("result")
            print("working in the background")
        
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=background_proc)
        process.start()
```